# Стриминг с Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, nginx, поиск-библиотек

Необходимо реализовать веб-сервис, который будет транслировать в реальном времени видеоконтент. Данные с медиаконтентом буду получать по протоколу `hls`.

Как можно обработать их и вывести на клиент? Что искать?

Стек: `Python`, `Django`, `Nginx`

Comment: Транслировать откуда? Опишите подробнее задачу, возможно Python вообще не понадобится

Comment: @andreymal, Сейчас разобрался немного, у нас есть ссылка на стрим от стримингового сервиса и мне нужно написать бэк для распределения потока пользователей. Пока думаю

Comment: Всё равно непонятно. Вы хотите взять уже готовый стрим и раздать его пользователям через свой сервер? Этот готовый стрим в каком формате стримится? И что мешает просто дать пользователям ссылку на этот готовый стрим от стримингового сервиса?

Comment: @andreymal  Да, у меня имеется поток от одного сервера, по сути мы имеем 10к запросов по адресу. Нужно разработать бэк, который должен давать потоки с наименьшими запросами на главный адресб так как физически сеть очень узкая к главному стриму.

Comment: Какой формат/протокол у этого потока? Тоже hls или какой-то другой?

Comment: @andreymal  да,  hls,  как я понял, примерно понял что делать нужно, потратил около 20 часов на разбор xD
Вы сталкивались с таким?
Есть мысли на этот счет?

Comment: Для этого достаточно взять любой hls-proxy (на гитхабе есть несколько реализаций) и раздать проксируемые файлы стрима через nginx (впрочем, сам я не пробовал)

Comment: @andreymal  Нашел  m3u8, буду разбираться. От души)

Comment: Или как вариант можно взять ffmpeg (который сможет прочитать любой стрим с любого протокола) и сделать копирование потока (без транскодирования) в hls-вывод, который потом раздать через тот же nginx. Но в таком случае он перепакует файлы стрима по-своему, в то время как всякие hls-proxy скорее всего будут максимально соответствовать оригиналу (впрочем, возможно, ничего плохого в этом нет)

Comment: Хорошо, буду разбираться, спасибо за советы!

Answer (score 0):

Django - синхронный и однопоточный фреймворк, поэтому не подходит для такой задачи. Один пользователь займёт воркер на всю продолжительность трансляции, десяток пользователей исчерпают пул воркеров, и новые пользователя будут получать таймаут при попытке подключиться к сервису. Вам нужно что-нибудь асинхронное.

Answer (score 0):

[Django-channels](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) даёт возможность писать асинхронные методы обработки запросов изначально синхронного и однопоточного Django. Я думаю, что это поможет решить вашу задачу.

Comment: Покажите пример, как можно с помощью channels раздавать видеопоток?